# como usar as propriedades inherit e initial no css?

Tags: css

Meus estudos de CSS resultaram em encontrar as seguintes propriedades: `inherit` e `initial`. Os dois a primeira vista me pareceu bastante semelhante, porém eu queria saber mesmo é:

**Onde eu posso usar inherit e initial?**

**Em que situações eu não devo usar inherit e initial?**

Inicialmente eu achei os termos semelhantes, mas seria bom explicarem a diferença entre os dois.

Comment: Leia esse artigo: https://tableless.com.br/entendendo-os-valores-initial-e-inherit-do-css/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente o **initial** retorna o valor inicial do browser, então dependendo do browser que você usa ele pode retornar um valor diferente.

O **inherit** checa o valor do elemento pai, por exemplo:

```css
div{
color:red;
}
h1{
color:inherit;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h1>teste</h1>
</div>
```

Se você colocar o **h1** com o valor **initial** ele irá mudar a cor para preto, que é o padrão do navegador.